# How to add multiple .AddFile in FLurl?

Tags: c#, flurl

I have this code will implement `Flurl` to call web api. But it only works for one file as I have fixed to the first element of `SupportingDocs` list object.

```
var response = await url.SetQueryParams(new { id, code })                     
        .PostMultipartAsync(mp => mp
        .AddFile("SupportingDocs", postData.SupportingDocs[0].FileContent, 
            postData.SupportingDocs[0].FileName)
        );
```

How do I add a foreach inside so that it can support multiple element for `SupportingDocs` which is a list object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the action delegate like this:

```cs
var response = await url.SetQueryParams(new { id, code })                     
    .PostMultipartAsync(mp => 
    {
        foreach (var doc in postData.SupportingDocs)
        {
            mp = mp.AddFile("SupportingDocs", doc.FileContent, doc.FileName);
        }
    });
```